# Updating table to Excel

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

I'm trying to "update" data that is placed into cells on a dataGridView.  I import data from an Excel file into a dataGridView. Using this method;

```
public static void updateTable1(string myNameRange, string mySET, string myWHERE)
{
    string sql = null;
    sql = "UPDATE " + myNameRange + " SET " + mySET + "' WHERE " + myWHERE + "'";
    //sql = "INSERT INTO" + myNameRange + " SET " + mySET + "'";
    myCommand.CommandText = sql;
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
}
```

If we have Column Headers NAME and AGE, if I input a table with Names Jack and Mike ages 10 and 20, if I change Jacks age from 10 to 30, this works.  The code says. Where Column NAME = Jack then Set Column AGE to 30.  This again works great.  The problem is what if I want to change the NAME and AGE. So change Jack to Matt, and Change Mikes age to 40.  OR  Add another Name and age to my table. This way wont work.  Is there a simple way to just Update the entire table with any changes made?

Comment: you need some additional conditional Logic like `AND` also what if there are multiple Jacks in your table how are you to know which one to update.. you need another Key to reference off of. you need a way to track the newly updated record .. so tracking the ID or Primary Key or some other Key index would also help so perhaps you can create a Stored Procedure and use one SP that can handle the INSERT and UPDATE declare some variables, Set them based on the condition and create an `out` Param if needed

Answer (score 0):

Consider you have 3 textboxes where user fills in NAME and AGE (and old name):

Create a method to which will check:

1. how may of the textboxes are filled
2. if the name enter in last textbox exists in DB

suppose Check is this method:

```
public static void updateTable1(string myNameRange, string mySET, string myWHERE)
    {
        if (Check()==0)/// Suppose 0 means all textboxes filled and name2 exists in DB
       {      
        string sql = "UPDATE myTable SET  NAME=@name , AGE=@age  WHERE Name=@name2";

        myCommand.CommandText = sql;
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", textBox1.text);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", textBox2.text);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name2", textBox3.text);
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        else if  (Check()==1)/// Suppose 1 means only name filled and name2 exists in DB
        {
          string sql = "UPDATE myTable SET  NAME=@name  WHERE Name=@name2";      
        myCommand.CommandText = sql;
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", textBox1.text);       
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name2", textBox3.text);
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        ....
        else /// (name2 not in DB)
        {
         sql = "INSERT INTO" + myNameRange + " SET " + mySET + "'";
          ///.......
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        Create stored procedure like the sample one below, here you only pass all the values that were changed, then the stored procedure will take care of the update. 

        public static void updateTable1(string? NameValue, int? AgeValue, int uniqueValue)
        {
            try 
            {           
                SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();
                myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                myCommand.CommandText = "spUpdate_ProcName";
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", NameValue);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", AgeValue);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UniqueColumn", uniqueValue);
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {       
                throw;
            }


        }
        //To be done in SQL
        CREATE PROCEDURE upProcName
        (
            @Name varchar(100) = NULL,
            @Age int = NULL,
            @UniqueColumn int -- unique column or primary key
        )
        AS
        BEGIN
            SET NOCOUNT ON;

            UPDATE yourTableName
            SET Name = COALESCE(@Name, Name),
                Age = COALESCE(@Age, Age)
            WHERE UniqueColumn = @UniqueColumn
        END
```